# asp.net como cambiar la imagen SVG en pagina html desde el codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg

Necesito cambiar la imagen (SVG) que esta en la pagina en un contendor tipo **object**  al seleccionar otro item dentro de dropdownlist.
Tiene que estar en el CodeBehind, utilizando el evento OnSelectedIndexChanged. Por defecto carga el grafico Imagen.svg, pero al seleccionar otro item de dropdownlista tendria que cambiar, cargando otra imagen que esta guardada en el mismo directorio.

El codigo del aspx es:

```
<td class="auto-style24" style="vertical-align: top;">
                Punto de Medición<br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPuntoMedicion" runat="server" DataSourceID="EDFPtoMedicion" DataTextField="Nombre" DataValueField="Id" Width="150px" Height="25px" OnPreRender="DDLPuntoMedicion_PreRender" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLPuntoMedicion_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                 </td>
            <td >
                 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style24" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;">
                <object id="diagrama" type="image/svg+xml" data="Imagen/Imagen.svg" style="border: medium ridge #C0C0C0; width: auto; height: 480px;"></object>
            </td>
            <td >
```

El codigo en C# tendria que estar adentro de:

```
protected void DDLPuntoMedicion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pregunta parece sencilla, pero es más complicada de lo que parece.

En principio la típica solución de añadir en el html un `runat=server` no funciona porque en asp.net no existe el htmlcontrol "object".

Voy a dar un par de soluciones... escoge la que más te guste...

Si defines así el Object

```
<object id="diagrama" type="image/svg+xml" data="<%=PropiedadPublicaDelFormulario" style="border: medium ridge #C0C0C0; width: auto; height: 480px;"></object>
```

En el código necesitarías un

```
public string PropiedadPublicaDelFormulario{ get; set; }
```

Después en el `SelectedIndexChanged` simplemente le das un valor a  PropiedadPublicaDelFormulario y se debería cambiar el valor Object.

Otras soluciones pasan por usar un control `PlaceHolder` en vez del Object, y en el evento crear un `LiteralControl` o `HtmlGenericControl` de forma manual.

Comment: La propiedad `PropiedadPublicaDelFormulario` cada vez que haga un `postback` va a perder su valor, para ello es necesario implementarlo con un [`ViewState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.110).aspx). Corrígeme si me equivoco.

Comment: Si, aunque puedes poner cualquier valor del formulario... por ejemplo DDLPuntoMedicion.Text y los controles de .net por defecto tienen activo el viewstate (ojo, lo escribo de memoria... lo digo para que te hagas una idea)

Comment: Entonces... sería necesario indicarle al OP que es necesario implementar algo adicional a la propiedad `public string PropiedadPublicaDelFormulario{ get; set; }`, porque así solo no ayuda en mucho :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, voy a probar public string  Propiedad(get,set);